# Where to ask discursive questions about programming?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

As mentioned in the [FAQ of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), asking about favorites, advice or discussions is undesired on Stack Overflow.

So where should I ask these questions? I think that it is interesting and helpful to discuss frequently asked questions or hand out advice in common issues even if there is *no certain* correct answer.

Comment: I fear that the answer is going to be "nowhere in the network", or at most "take it to chat, if the room is willing to discuss it".

Comment: Similar to [Where to ask more general programming questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98353) and [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401)

Comment: What was wrong with this question?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find out if there is a non-discussion question at the core.

Don't ask "What is the best *foo*?", maybe "Why is a *foo* used and what should I consider when choosing?" is the better question.

Note that this is **not** just a cosmetic change, it will mean that you don't get the same "answers". But it will also mean that the answers are still relevant when a new *foo* is released 2 years down the road.

This also helps avoid a big "subjective" aspect: the answers can simply list common criteria (people *tend* to agree on those) and the actual *priorities* of those criteria is up to every single person to decide (because this is where peoples opinions tend to separate).